# From python to AIML

Tags: python, aiml

I'm trying to create my first chatbot that I want to use for my home automation project.

This might sound stupid and maybe this is not the way to go but I would like to have your opinion and perhaps a way to make it work.

I want to be able to ask my bot what is my location and I want it to run my python code that returns my current location and then get an answer with that.

This is my **location.py**

```
from pyicloud import PyiCloudService
import googlemaps
import aiml


api_key = "##################3"

gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key= api_key)

api = PyiCloudService('###email####','###password###')

longitude = api.iphone.location()['longitude']
latitude = api.iphone.location()['latitude']


current_location  = gmaps.reverse_geocode((latitude, longitude))
street = current_location[0]['address_components'][1]['long_name']
house_number = current_location[0]['address_components'][0]['long_name']


def get_location():
    current_location = ('%s,%s' % (street, house_number))
    return current_location
```

Now I don know how to get this into my aiml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <aiml>
<category>
<pattern>WHAT IS MY LOCATION</pattern>
<template>??????</template>
</category>

</aiml>
```

I hope this makes some sense :)

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If your location is Chicago, You can use `kernel.setPredicate("location", "Chicago")` in Python and then put out the value in AIML like this:

```
<category>
<pattern>WHAT IS MY LOCATION</pattern>
<template>Your location: <get name="location"></get></template>
</category>
```

Check out an [examples here](http://www.devdungeon.com/content/ai-chat-bot-python-aiml).